# How to black out chrome window trim with rain guards?

Tags: trim

For starters, this question isn't necessarily for a specific car. Having said that, I have a 5th generation Subaru Legacy (2010-2014), as pictured here: [image]

I have some rainguards to install which includes some clips and double-sided tape that is pressed against the chrome trim. However, since the rain guards are slightly transparent, I want to black out or delete all of the chrome trim first. I've been considering using plastidip or paint on the trim, or possibly having them wrapped with black vinyl prior to installing the rain guards. But, I'm concerned that I could possibly be compromising how secure the rainguards are attached to the vehicle.

Accounting for securely adhering the rainguards and ensuring a durable solution in general, what is the best way to black out or otherwise delete the chrome trim before I install the rainguards?

Comment: There are so many ways this can be done. I think you are just going to get a number of opinions on what is the best way. Might be a good idea to contact a local body shop for advice.

Comment: @CharlieRB: Really? I've only determined 2 ways to do this, and I've been thinking about this and asking around for quite some time. As for local body shops, they tend to be unhelpful when I present this kind of problem to them, and vinyl wrap isn't their forte.

Comment: As for this being opinion based, I strongly disagree. I've laid out pretty clear criteria. If it wasn't for the rainguards, I wouldn't have bothered asking because just about anything will work. But that's not my situation. I'm planning to tape on some pieces of plastic that weigh a not-insignificant amount. I want whatever solution I use to black out the chrome to also be capable of supporting that weight. I need *clear reasons* that a particular solution will support those rainguards, since they will be subjected to windy conditions on highways.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but when you ask "*what is the best way*", you are asking for opinions. I was referring to "*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*" in the guidelines.

Comment: @CharlieRB: No, what I'm asking are for viable solutions. "Just wrap it in black construction paper" is not viable. If I remove the word "best" from the one sentence you seem to object to, it doesn't change what I'm asking in any way. I should still get the same answers while voting and the green checkmark will reveal which answer is the best.